# How to determine how many knots and where to place them in a data set

Tags: r, splines

I am working with the Boston data set and I want to graph age and medv in this dataset and then determine the number of knots that would best fit between this data and also what they are. I am not too sure how to change the number of knots or how to determine the values in the 3 quartiles. I am new to R and I cant find much information on how to determine the best number of knot.

For now I just plotted the cubic spline:

```r
library(MASS)
library(ISLR)
library (splines )

age.grid = 0:100
fitbs=lm(medv~bs(age,knots=c(25,40,60),degree=3),data=Boston)
predbs = predict(fitbs, newdata = list(age = age.grid), se.fit = TRUE) 

plot(Boston$age, Boston$medv, col = "darkgray",
     main = 'Cubic spline', bty = 'l', 
     xlab = 'age', ylab = 'medv', ylim = c(0,55))
lines(age.grid, predbs$fit, lwd = 2)
lines(age.grid,predbs$fit+2*predbs$se,lty="dashed") 
lines(age.grid,predbs$fit-2*predbs$se,lty="dashed")
```

Comment: Hi Lyla_H07, welcome to SO. This type of question is much easier to answer definitively if it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Comment: Hi L Tyrone I fixed it I just added what I have so far, thank you!

Comment: @Lyla_H07 you didn't define `age.grid` in your example (and I assume `fitbs` is the same as the `bs` fit, `pred` the same as `predbs`), I'm guessing the reason your regression line only gets plotted up to 80 is that that is the maximum value you're asking predictions for.